# Coalesce columns in pyspark dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, coalesce

> > > res=to.join(tc, to.id1 == tc.id,how='left').select(to.id1.alias('Employee_id'), tc.name.alias('Employee_Name'), to.dept.alias('Employee_Dept'))
> > >       res.show()

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|Employee_id|Employee_Name|Employee_Dept|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|         12|         Prad|      Physics|
|         13|         null|         Chem|
|         14|         null|        Maths|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to replace the null with say NONAME. Please advise the select syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df.withColumn("EmployeeNameNoNull",coalesce(df.Employee_Name,lit('NONAME'))).show()
```

Comment: @AravindP can you please click on the check mark to mark the question as answered if it helped you?